# Wamp server not working after opening port 81

Tags: wampserver, windows-server-2012

i am hoping you can help.

I have just started hiring a web server from hetzner.

I loaded wamp onto the server, but as it is a windows 2012 server, it's port 80 is being used by the default loaded IIS.
So i opened up the port 81, for wamp, but it has been a struggle, when i type in my browser localhost:81 it shows me wamp server homepage, but whenever i try to enter into the phpmyadmin page, it's loaded, but i just see a white screen, i cannot enter the database management.

Does anybody know what might have caused this?

Comment: white screen on a php system means something blew up and error_reporting/display_errors are off. Turn on those options and try again, and/or look at the server error logs to see what's happening.

Comment: I have had similar experiences (I can't remember the solution) but it could be to do with the permissions of mysql or php (apache) on the server, maybe post this to Server Fault rather than stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If you are using port 81 ( or any non standard port ) you have to add the port number to all your url's.

So try using

```
http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin
```

and it will work.

If you are not using IIS I would suggest disabling it and all its friend that grab port 80 so you can move wamp's Apache back to port 80.

Comment: i do add :81, i can see the wamp screen, but not the phpmyadmin screen, only when i log into my admin, does the screen only show white.